Unable to fetch data from first table into another based on more than 1 parameter
Please refer the data dump table below first.



Category
Brand
Transaction Amount




Category1
A
10


Category1
B
20


Category1
C
30


Category1
A
30


Category2
D
40


Category2
E
15


Category2
E



Category2
E
15



This is the an example of the table i am working on. Now there 10-11 categories and each category has 6-7 unique brands and may/may not have transaction amount in front of them.
Now i want to print the brand names with highest sum of transaction amount per category in below result table.
This is easily doable by pivot by i want to achieve this using formula but unable to do so.
This is the result table, where i should receive name of brands with highest sum of transaction for each category.
Update: I can list the unique categories. just need the formulae to find the brand with highest sum of transaction for that specific category, thanks!



Category
Brand
Sum of Transaction




Category1
A
40


Category2
D
40




Here is one way of doing this using MS365:

=LET(
     α, A2:B9,
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, TAKE(α,,-1),
     TAKE(SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,BYROW(α,LAMBDA(x,
     SUM((TAKE(x,,1)=δ)*(TAKE(x,,-1)=φ)*C2:C9))))),{3,1},{-1,1}),ROWS(UNIQUE(δ))))


And If applicable using GROUPBY()


=LET(
     _Data, GROUPBY(A2:B9,C2:C9,SUM,,0,-3),
     _Cat, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Cat),
     CHOOSEROWS(_Data, XMATCH( _Uniq, _Cat)))


Or, Using the BYROW() with CHOOSEROWS() + XMATCH()
=LET(
     _Data, A2:B9,
     _Cat, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Brand, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _Vals, BYROW(_Data,LAMBDA(x,SUM((TAKE(x,,1)=_Cat)*(TAKE(x,,-1)=_Brand)*C2:C9))),
     _Sorted, SORT(HSTACK(_Data,_Vals),{3,1},{-1,1}),
     CHOOSEROWS(_Sorted, XMATCH(UNIQUE(_Cat),TAKE(_Sorted,,1))))


Also to make it more simpler, if one has listed the categories take advantage of the following:


=TAKE(UNIQUE(SORT(HSTACK($A2:$B9,SUMIFS($C2:$C9,$A2:$A9,E13,$B2:$B9,$B2:$B9)),3,-1)),1,-2)



Thanks for the answer! One single formulae created whole table. Honestly can't understand even a single line of code but works perfectly.
Where did you learn advanced excel from?

@DivijGoyal strange you dont understand this formula, even the final one is more easier to understand, but you can understand long formulas. anyways try researching here you will learn later or sooner.

hey mayukh, just one more question. if i am defining the start and end cell values in sumifs criteria range, the formulae is working. as soon as i selected whole columns for criteria range formulae started returning 0(i tried the sumifs formula separately to test this.)

@DivijGoyal using blank rows is not recommended or suggested it reduces the efficiency of Excel. Instead use structured references aka tables to use in the formulas. and that is a bad concept of using the whole ranges.

using complete columns since new data might get added in the data dump sheet and then i would have to update the formulaes again. should i select complete column and use filter?

@DivijGoyal that is why i have asked you to use structured references.

@DivijGoyal also if you want to use the whole range, you could try : =LET(_Data, FILTER(A:C,MMULT(N(A:C<>""),{1;1;1})>1),TAKE(UNIQUE(SORT(HSTACK(TAKE(_Data, ,2),SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, E13, B:B, INDEX(_Data,,2))),3,-1)),1,-2)) or have to consider a base column, so as to get the last row, if reluctant to use Tables

@DivijGoyal but this will be slow note that. using tables is better.

Complete redo, requires two steps unlike user's answer:
In column E use: =UNIQUE(A2:A9)
In column F use: =INDEX(HSTACK(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),$A$2:$A$9,E2)),MATCH(MAX(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),$A$2:$A$9,E2)),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),$A$2:$A$9,E2),0),0)
Drag down as required. (and change ranges as required)
As per requested in the comments: Only output the Brand name with the highest transaction sum.
=INDEX(HSTACK(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),$A$2:$A$9,E2)),MATCH(MAX(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),$A$2:$A$9,E2)),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9=E2)),$A$2:$A$9,E2),0),1)

yes sir, this is what i was looking for. by using index match. Can you please update this formulae so that it just gives the brand name and not the sum of transactions?

@DivijGoyal I added an update, check if that satisfies your needs.

works perfectly! thanks a lot sir! how did you get this good at excel? i am a beginner for reference. any tips/resources that i should follow?

@DivijGoyal I'm not that good (look at Mayukh's answer, much more compact), but I just practice a lot, trying out new things, think how they work and how I can make them work. Also reading a lot of questions and answers on here, most of which I'll probably never apply to my own needs, but I still know a way to work around a certain problem, should I ever run into it.
